# Проблемы с проверкой времени и отправкой сообщения

Tags: python, время, datetime

Как правильно сохранять время которое сейчас и проверять так пока не поменяется на 1 минуту вперед, и когда поменяется уже определенные действия:
КОД:

```
while True:
    win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409', 1)  # меняет язык на англ.

    def pressed_key(e):
        res = e.name  # названия кнопки, например 'enter', 'caps lock' 
        if e.event_type == 'down':
            print(str(datetime.datetime.now().time())[:-10]) # узнаю время - вывод HH:MM


    keyboard.hook(pressed_key)
    keyboard.wait()
```

Нужно сделать чтобы когда поменялась минута, выполнить определенную функцию
Если не поменялась то пропустить

**Пример что мне нужно:**

```
*нажимаю клавиши

Время 15:50

print("время не меняется")
...
*нажимаю клавишУ*

время 15:51

print("время поменялось")

*нажимаю ещё раз клавишу*

print("время не поменялось")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:
Если всю логику обернуть в класс.

```py
import keyboard
import datetime

class ClassName():
    tm = "0"

    def __init__(self):
        keyboard.hook(self.pressed_key)
        keyboard.wait()

    def pressed_key(self, e):
        res = e.name  # названия кнопки, например 'enter', 'caps lock' 
        
        if e.event_type == 'down':
            tm_now = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())[:-10]
            if self.tm < tm_now:
                self.tm = tm_now
                print("Время ",tm_now)

            elif self.tm == tm_now:
                print("время не меняется")

ClassName()
```

Comment: Ещё вопрос, а если время поменяется с 23:59 на 00:00, второе не будет считаться меньшим? Так как идёт уравнения if self.tm < tm_now: ?

Comment: да скорее всего будет. Но можно использовать не только часы и минуты но более полную дату.

Comment: Ну я добавил ещё else: , а выполнения аналогичное как у if self.tm < tm_now. Всё работает. А мне не нужно очень точно измерять, это чтобы каждую минуту высылался запрос, поэтому всё окей.

Comment: @VitalikShchudlo, можно просто сравнивать - отличается ли время!

Comment: Да-да. Переделал, теперь if self.tm != tm_now: #если разное и else: #не меняется, БЛАГОДАРЮ :)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сравнивать время достаточно и минут:

```
import keyboard

from datetime import datetime

last_time = datetime.now().minute

def pressed_key(e):
    global last_time
    res = e.name  # названия кнопки, например 'enter', 'caps lock' 
    if e.event_type == 'down':
        print(':'.join(str(datetime.now()).split('.')[0].split(':')[:-1]))
        now_time = datetime.now().minute
        if now_time != last_time:
            print('Время поменялось!')
        else:
            print('Время не поменялось!')
        last_time = now_time


while True:
    win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409', 1)  # меняет язык на англ.
    keyboard.hook(pressed_key)
    keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: Так я добавил `global last_time`

Comment: Так переменная то глобальная

Comment: i=10  
def a():
    global i;i = 20
a()
print(i)
#20